# Using a scanner and split and storing the data in an array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a segment of code that has to scan text from a file and store it in an array of Strings. My code looks like this

```
 else if (e.getSource()==readButton){
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("src");
        if  (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            empFile=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
            Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");
            while(scan.hasNext()){
                String[] rowData = scan.nextLine().split(":");
                if(rowData.length == 5){
                    rowData[4] = null;
                    fName = rowData[0];
                    lName = rowData[1];
                    position2 = rowData[2];
                    firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
                    secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
                    empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]);
                }
                else{
                fName = rowData[0];
                lName = rowData[1];
                position2 = rowData[2];
                firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
                secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
                empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]);
                }
                if (position2.equals("Manager")){
                    c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, 0, empNum);
                }
                else if(position2.equals("Sales")){
                    c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, 0, empNum);
                }
                else{
                    c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, secondParam, empNum);
                }
            }
            
        }
```

And the text that is being scanned looks like this

> John:Smith:Manufacturing:6.75:120:444
>
> Betty:White:Manager:1200.00:111
>
> Stan:Slimy:Sales:10000.00:332
>
> Betty:Boop:Design:12.50:50:244

How can I make it scan one line store it in an array then use the addEmployee method for 6 or 5 parameters then move on to the next line. The text sometimes has 5 stuff and because there is 5 the secondParam or rowData[4] should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You set the

```
         rowData[4] = null;
```

and then after you parse it

```
 secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
```

youll get numberformatexception from that;

**just set it to 0:**

```
rowData[4] = "0";
```

Also you checked the lenght if it is 5 but you add the 5th index which is the 6th string in the array.. it will cause null pointer exception.. just take it out

```
if(rowData.length == 5){
                rowData[4] = "0";
                fName = rowData[0];
                lName = rowData[1];
                position2 = rowData[2];
                firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
                secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
            }
```

UPDATED:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String[] rowData = scan.nextLine().split(":");
            if(rowData.length == 5){
                rowData[4] = "0";
                fName = rowData[0];
                lName = rowData[1];
                position2 = rowData[2];
                firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
                empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);

                c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, 0, empNum);

            }
            else{
            fName = rowData[0];
            lName = rowData[1];
            position2 = rowData[2];
            firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
            secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
            empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]);

             c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, secondParam, empNum);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but my question is how can I make it scan one line store it in an array then use the addEmployee method for 6 or 5 parameters then move on to the next line and repeat until all of the text is read.

Comment: Ok thanks again for the reply I think this may do the trick but I still can't get rid of the "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at GUI$aListener.actionPerformed(GUI.java:340)" error and line 340 is the lName = rowData[1]; of the else statement. Could you help me with that aswell?